# Libreoffice insert continuous page number

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to insert page number in my libreoffice-writer. But, libre is showing 2 page counting [image: Screenshot of the infobar]

So, when I am inserting page number, the number count from the `[]` is showing. So, in this present page,I will get page number 4, not 12.

How I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

(source: https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/swriter/01/04090001.html?System=WIN&DbPAR=WRITER&HID=modules/swriter/ui/flddocumentpage/FieldDocumentPage#bm_@@nowidget@@ )

> [Offset](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/swriter/01/04090001.html?System=WIN&DbPAR=WRITER&HID=modules/swriter/ui/flddocumentpage/FieldDocumentPage#bm_@@nowidget@@:%7E:text=the%20inserted%20field.-,Offset,-Enter%20the%20offset)
> Enter the offset value that you want to apply to a page number
> field, for example "+1".
>
> With an Offset value of 1, the field will display a number that is 1
> more than the current page number, but only if a page with that number
> exists. On the last page of the document, this same field will be
> empty.
>
> tip If you want to change the actual page number and not the displayed
> number, do not use the Offset value. To change page numbers, read the
> [Page Numbers](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/swriter/guide/pagenumbers.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=WIN) guide.

[To Start With a Defined Page Number](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/swriter/guide/pagenumbers.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=WIN#:%7E:text=current%20page%20style.-,To%20Start%20With%20a%20Defined%20Page%20Number,To,-Select%20the%20Page)

> Now you want some more control on page numbers. You are writing a text document that should start with page number 12.
>
> Click into the first paragraph of your document.
>
> Choose Format - Paragraph - Text flow tab.
>
> In the Breaks area, enable Insert. Enable With Page Style just to be able to set the new Page number. Click OK.
>
> Note Icon
> The new page number is an attribute of the first paragraph of the page.